# UIWebView inside UITableViewCell flash white and incorrect size

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

this is the repo i made.

https://github.com/lifesaglitch/UIWebViewFlashWhite

The basic idea is:

I have an expandable table view, with 2 cells: header cell and content cell.

when click on header cell, I insert a content cell, and load a html string to the web view, which is a subview of the content cell.

If it's the first time I expand a cell, the web view has a white flash, with the correct frame size. There may be flash as well for the subsequent expand, but the frame size is wrong.

what I have tried (in the project) is to set the color to clear, which does not work. I also tried a webview's delegate, set hidden = NO after the html string was loaded, but sometimes the delegate call back is not called. Maybe it's because the reusable mechanism.

Please download my project from above link and try it out.

Here are some sample code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }

    return self;
}
```

data source method:

```
    ContentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];
    [cell.contentView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style='background-color: #ff0000'>this is contentasdoifjoiwjeofiqjweoifjqopweifj </body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

EDIT:

I have committed a new version: use placeholder to hide the webview first, and unhide it when it's loaded, but there is still white flash screen.

Comment: Why you do nothing in your repo?

Comment: i set the background color as clear color, which does not work

Comment: I mean no UItableView, no datasource, nothing in self.view after I download. Like a new project

Comment: let me check, sorry about it.

Comment: @stack forgot to push last time, you can download it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to modify your expand/collapse animation to HeaderView like [Apple sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)
or [this tutorial](http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/)

Then, you need to modify your code in ContentCell.h and ContentCell.m
 Don't hook up contentView property with other IBOutlet, your view
    after drag to tableCell will be a subView of it. SupperView and
    Subview have same name can cause crash.Choose cellWebView name and hook up with your UIWebView:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.cellWebView setOpaque:NO];//Need to clear background of UIWebView
    self.cellWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: dont forget to put [super awakeFromNib]. Is it because awakeFromNib is called before init method?